# How could I refer to built-in MS Excel type with OLE

Tags: excel, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, excel-2010

my application should perform some simple actions in Excel, like adding charts, list objects and so on. I'm using OLE connection. The problem is, that some Excel methods taking built-in types (enumerations) as arguments. And I have no ideas about referring to them. For example:

```
WorkBook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$D$5:$J$15"), , xlNo).Name = "Table1"
```

**xlSrcRange** and **xlNo** belong to the built-in enumeration. I tried to refer to them in a following way

```
ExcelApp.xlSrcRange
ExcelApp.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange
ExcelApp.XlListObjectSourceType
```

this code causes error "Object doesn't support property or method *ExcelApp.xlSrcRange*"

```
New XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange
new xlSrcRange
```

this code causes an error too (unknown variable XlListObjectSourceType and xlSrcRange)

I'm working with QTP and the script language is VB-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .wsf script can access the xl* constants via a Excel.Sheet reference:

```
type xlconst.wsf

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<package>
 <job id="xlconst">
  <reference object="Excel.Sheet" reference="true"/>
  <script language="VBScript">
   <![CDATA[
' ############################################################################
For Each arg In WScript.Arguments.Unnamed
    WScript.Echo "Const " & arg & " = " & Eval(arg)
Next
' ############################################################################
   ]]>
  </script>
 </job>
</package>
```

output:

```
cscript xlconst.wsf xlNo xlYes

Const xlNo = 2
Const xlYes = 1
```

Plain VBScript can't. If QTP is restricted to plain VBScript, you'll have to add/define the constants manually. Perhaps the above .wsf will make this task easier.

Answer (score 0):

How about using fully qualified name?

```
dim sourceType As Excel.XlListObjectSourceType
sourceType = Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange
```

EDIT: (in vbscript)

```
dim sourceType 
sourceType = 1
```

Comment: In this version of VB-script construction "DIM <var> AS <type>" is illegal. The next statement causes an error i've mentioned in topic